# How to convert FB Like button to haml

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

Just starting out with HAML, how do I convert this?

`<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://localhost:3000" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>`

Comment: I've answered your question below but do consider reading the documentation or at least doing a quick google before asking on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation link](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#attributes)

Answer:

.fb-like{"data-href" => "http://localhost:3000", "data-send" => "true", "data-show-faces" => "false", "data-width" => "450"}

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that actually didn't work, as it's not recognizing any of the other code in the brackets

Comment: Ah you might try to take the `"` off the boolean values as well as look at [this](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#html5_custom_data_attributes). I haven't used HAML much but the documentation seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: I have edited my answer and that should work. I tried it [here](http://html2haml.heroku.com/).

Answer (score 1):

.fb-like{:data => {:href => 'http://localhost:3000', :send => 'true', :show-faces => 'false', :width => '450'}}